# Mass update og Price Lists through CSV

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have this functionality that updates Price Lists from an CSV file, but takes way too long to fulfill (9 hours aprox.).

The structure file have 2 main parts, the record lines (rows) and 10 possible dimensions (not AX dimensions) of types of price (columns).

It's already working, but customer is asking for alternatives since the process takes too much time to complete.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Data import/export framework  (DIXF, DMF):
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj225591.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Or a third party product called Atlas:
http://globesoftware.com/Atlas-Solution/Why-Atlas

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should consider why it takes so long?

I have implemented a similar solution. Reading from CSV to a staging table run with at least one thousand lines per second. Updating the price table is slower but at least 100 per second.

Things to consider is index usage and, if possible, use of record set updates.

Consider [using tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149695.aspx) to benchmark your solution.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking using third party tools ... but that implies changing the  functionality's architecture